# References not showing up

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

I have created a .bib file using Jabref. Now I placed this file in the same folder where all my other latex fles are present. I am adding the reference to this .bib file using this:

```
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{jab}
```

I am compiling my latex code on WinEdt but afterwards the file generated does not contain any references. Reference part is just blank.

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Have you run `bibtex`?

Comment: And did you actually cite something? Only cited entries are listed, unless you issue an `\nocite{*}` (plus latex, bibtex, latex, latex) which lists everything from the `.bib` file.

Comment: @daleif I have not made much citations yet. But when I run bibtex, it says \no bibstyle command.... . I added \nocite{*} above \bibliography but still nothing appears.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I added \nocite{*} after \bibliograpghy

Comment: `\nocite{*}` can be anywhere in the document. The important thing is the `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` (at least when you have normal citations, like `\cite`